# Проблема с scala+maven+tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, scala

Такая вот беда. Не получается запустить проект на скала через Tomcat. Пытался и в обычный еклипс подкидывать скалу и в ScalaIDE тоже пытался. В чем беда. Просто мавен проект запускается без каких либо проблем. Когда правой кнопкой нажимаешь на мавен проект то там есть опция "Run on server". А на скала проекте созданном при помощи команды "mvn archetype:generate №541: remote -> net.alchim31.maven:scala-archetype-simple (The maven-scala-plugin is used for compiling/testing/running/documenting scala code in maven.)" нет такой команды, если создавать в Run Configuration то при запуске говорит что ему не хватает bootstrap. Подкидываю его в ClassPath и потом он почему то ищет классы Томката в дериктории еклипса. Но путь catalina_home и путь в переменной Path есть. Я подкидываю томкат в корень eclipse и все работает томкат запускает сервер. Все было бы хорошо, но не открывается привычное окошко "мини-барузера" в самой еклипсе, по этому захожу через браузер. И как бы я не старался не могу насчупать свой проект. Приложил проект целиком. ОС Windows 10. Если вы уже делали такое. Или вы знаете как. Сделайте у себя на компьютере и объясните пошагово что делать. Может у меня и в коде что то не так. Хотя должно в любом случае откликаться. Если у вас есть возможность настроить и скинуть мне настроенную еклипсу то вообще отлично.
Облазил весь гугл не знаю что делать.
Ссылка на мой проект https://yadi.sk/d/mcBt5mQCqDWDj

Answer (score 1):

Это все делается гараздо проще, надо создать обычный проект на java, а затем перевести его в scala, подкинув несколько зависимостей.